# Directory Browsing on Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, jquery

I am listing a couple of stuff that I want people to download for my school and remembered that some sites had directory browsing done with cool little icons displaying the file types. I wanted to do this myself and felt that the default directory browsing of apache is just too plain and IndexOptions +FancyIndexing is a bit 'old'. Any nice jQuery based Web 2.0ish stuff out there for this particular purpose. The files are .debs, .exes, .iso, .zip etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are too many to list, but what you probably want is a web based file manager:

A few search terms you may want : "[WYSIWYG online file manager](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&q=WYSIWYG+online+file+manager&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=WYSIWYG+online+file+manager)", "[ajax online file manager](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=ajax+online+file+manager&meta=&aq=f&oq=ajax+online+file+manager)" and "[php file manager](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=php+file+manager&meta=&aq=&oq=php+file+manager)".

An example of result:

[Ajax File Manager](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Ajax-File--Manager/)

[image]

Again, there are too many to list, but take a look and I am sure you will find one you like.